# Graph theory - torus proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple graph that can be embedded on a torus so that every region is bordered by exactly $3$ edges. Find (with a proof) all the possible values for the quantity
$|V | − |E| + r$,
where $r$ is the number of regions that the graph $G$ can split the torus.

So the torus will be covered in $C_3$'s connected to each other. I'm not really sure what to do with that information. Any help/hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangulated graph on a plane is maximal planar i.e. we cannot add a new edge without introducing an edge crossing. It is easy to see how on a plane a triangulated graph is maximal planar. By extending the similar logic, or you prove rigorously that a triangulated graph on a torus is also maximal (or maximal torus), i.e., you cannot add an edge without introducing an edge crossing.

Now a maximal torus graph is either maximal planar or non planar. If it is maximal planar, $\gamma(G)=0$ and if it is non-planar (and we know it can be embedded on a torus), $\gamma(G)=1$. Hence, the value of $|V|-|E|+r$ is either 2 or 0.